# Create animation by changing image in ImageView with Timer (or Handler)

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview, android-drawable, animationdrawable

I want to create an simple animation by changing frames inside an ImageView. I don't want to use AnimationDrawable because i need to receive events when a frame changed or when the animation stoped, to be able to play it backwards, restart it and so on.

My problem is that the frames doesn't actually change event though setImageDrawable gets called (on the main thread). So everythings seems to work fine excepts that the frames doesn't change (actually just a frame is drawn, the first one).

So my code:

```
public class AnimatedImageView extends ImageView implements Animatable, Runnable {

    private static final String TAG = "AnimatedImageView";

    public static interface AnimationEventsListener {
        void animationDidChangeFrame(AnimatedImageView animatedImageView);

        void animationDidStop(AnimatedImageView animatedImageView);
    }

    /* frames - ress ids */
    private int[] mFrameResIds;
    /* current frame index */
    private int mCurrentFrameIdx;
    /* number of the current repeat */
    private int loopIndex;
    /* number of animation repetiotions, 0 for infinite */
    private int mNumOfRepetitions;
    /* if animation is playing */
    private boolean playing;
    /* if animation is paused */
    private boolean paused;
    /* if animation is playing backward */
    private boolean playItBackward;
    /* animation duration */
    private long mAnimationDuration;
    /* frame animation duration (mAnimationDuration / num_of_frames) */
    private long mFrameAnimationDuration;

    /* listener for animation events */
    private AnimationEventsListener mListener;

    private Handler mHandler;

    public AnimatedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public AnimatedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public AnimatedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        this.setClickable(true);
        Logger.d("MSG", "setup, thread: " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (playing) {
            return;
        }
        mCurrentFrameIdx = playItBackward ? mFrameResIds.length - 1 : 0;
        loopIndex = 0;
        playing = true;
        updateFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        paused = true;
    }

    public void resume() {
        paused = false;
        playing = true;
        updateFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Logger.d("MSG", "run, thread: " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
        updateFrame();
    }

    public AnimationEventsListener getListener() {
        return mListener;
    }

    public void setListener(AnimationEventsListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    public long getAnimationDuration() {
        return mAnimationDuration;
    }

    public void setAnimationDuration(long mAnimationDuration) {
        this.mAnimationDuration = mAnimationDuration;
        if (mFrameResIds != null) {
            mFrameAnimationDuration = mAnimationDuration / mFrameResIds.length;
        }
    }

    public int[] getFrameResIds() {
        return mFrameResIds;
    }

    public void setFrameResIds(int[] mFrameResIds) {
        this.mFrameResIds = mFrameResIds;
        if (mFrameResIds != null) {
            mFrameAnimationDuration = mAnimationDuration / mFrameResIds.length;
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentFrame(int frameValue) {
        mCurrentFrameIdx = frameValue;
        this.setAnimationFrame(frameValue);
    }

    private void setAnimationFrame(int animationFrame) {
        Logger.d("MSG", "setAnimationFrame: " + animationFrame);
        if (animationFrame < 0) {
            animationFrame = 0;
        }

        if (animationFrame > -1) {
            animationFrame = mFrameResIds.length - 1;
        }

        Resources resources = getResources();
        AnimatedImageView.this.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(mFrameResIds[animationFrame]));
        AnimatedImageView.this.forceLayout();
//        AnimatedImageView.this.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, mFrameResIds[animationFrame]));
//        this.setImageResource(mFrameResIds[animationFrame]);
        AnimatedImageView.this.invalidate();
    }

    private void updateFrame() {
        Logger.d("MSG", "updateFrame " + mCurrentFrameIdx);
        if (!playing || paused) {
            return;
        }

        playing = false;

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.animationDidChangeFrame(AnimatedImageView.this);
        }

        if (!playItBackward) {
            mCurrentFrameIdx++;
            if (mCurrentFrameIdx >= mFrameResIds.length) {
                loopIndex++;
                mCurrentFrameIdx = 0;
                if (mNumOfRepetitions == loopIndex) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.animationDidStop(AnimatedImageView.this);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            mCurrentFrameIdx--;
            if (mCurrentFrameIdx < 0) {
                loopIndex++;
                mCurrentFrameIdx = mFrameResIds.length - 1;
                if (mNumOfRepetitions == loopIndex) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.animationDidStop(AnimatedImageView.this);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        playing = true;

        setAnimationFrame(mCurrentFrameIdx);
//        mHandler.postDelayed(AnimatedImageView.this, mFrameAnimationDuration);
//        scheduleDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(mFrameResIds[mCurrentFrameIdx]), AnimatedImageView.this, mFrameAnimationDuration);
//        postDelayed()
        postDelayed(AnimatedImageView.this, mFrameAnimationDuration);

//        SongPlayerActivity.handler.postDelayed(AnimatedImageView.this, mFrameAnimationDuration);
    }
```

I have an AnimatedImageView object in my layout in xml and in my activity i find it by id and start the animation on click:

```
final AnimatedImageView mDriverAnimation = (AnimatedImageView) findViewById(R.id.driver);
        mDriverAnimation.setFrameResIds(new int[]{R.drawable.song1_driver1, R.drawable.song1_driver2, R.drawable.song1_driver3});
        mDriverAnimation.setAnimationDuration(3 * 1000);
        mDriverAnimation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDriverAnimation.start();
            }
        });
```

Any ideas? :) Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I think that TransitionDrawable could solve your problem: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html

```
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = //your first drawable
layers[1] = //your second drawable
TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable(layers);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(transition);
transition.startTransition(1500);
```

Comment: not really, i want to be able to manually change the frame so i can call my listeners. If i use TransitionDrawable i still won't be notified after each frame. Thanks for your answer