# Android how to smoothly change background drawable of layout

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I need to change the background drawable for my linear layout smoothly, this is how i change the background drawable, but how i can add some animation when changing in?

```
 mylayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(HomeActivity.this, R.drawable.globebg));
```

Comment: you could use TransitionDrawable [this is answer seems well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19146570/3209523)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/5250273

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create custom view
And override onDraw function with animation
May be this will be more simple